# compute the following integral using Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi}{e^{k\cos t}\cos (k\sin t)}=\pi$. Using Cauchy Integral Formula. But I don't know how. I want to rewrite the integral as a line integral first.

Comment: Well, what is it that the CIF tells us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that one may exploit symmetry in the integral and rewrite as

$$\frac12 \int_0^{2 \pi} dt \, e^{k \cos{t}} \, \cos{(k \sin{t})}$$

Now sub $z=e^{i t}$, $dt = -i dz/z$, and note that

$$e^{k \cos{t}}  \, \cos{(k \sin{t})} = \Re{\left [ e^{k z}\right]}$$

(To see this, expand $e^{k e^{i t}}$ into real and imaginary parts.)  The integral is therefore equal to

$$\Re{\left [-\frac{i}{2} \oint_{|z|=1} dz\, \frac{e^{k z}}{z}\right]}$$

By Cauchy's theorem/residue theorem, the integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=0$, which is $1$.  The result to be shown follows.